Graph disconnected error on Grad-CAM model with Keras
The Grad-CAM model code below
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout

ModelInputShape = [640, 360, 3]

backbone = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    BatchNormalization(input_shape=ModelInputShape),
    tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetV2S(input_shape=ModelInputShape, include_top=False,
                                          weights=None)
], name='backbone')                                               

head = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    GlobalAveragePooling2D(),         
    Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(120, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')    
], name='head')

model = tf.keras.Sequential([backbone, head])

grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
    model.inputs, [model.output, model.output]     # works ok
)

grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
    model.inputs, [model.get_layer('backbone').layers[-1].layers[-1].output, model.output]     # raises error
)

raises an error below.
Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 640, 360, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'") at layer "rescaling". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
I cannot find where the graph is disconnected. Where should be fixed in the code above?

Hi @ Hyunjik, You are Trying  to want to use the output of the last layer in the architecture's backbone, which is likely not correctly linked with the model.output. Instead of accessing layers in this manner via model.get_layer(‘backbone’).layers, understanding that anatomy in complex and error-prone, it is better to get the output tensor from moving to the backbone model.
